# Get the 4 not repeated latest results on GQL (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Hello I have this on my GAE application:

```
try:
    last = RegistroDescargas.gql("order by date DESC LIMIT 4")
except:
    last = None
```

With that I can get the last four rows of the database ("RegistroDescagas") that is defined as follows:

```
class RegistroDescargas(db.Model):
    '''Model para guardar el registro de vídeos descargados en la web'''
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    urlOrig = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    urlImg = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    vidTit = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    vidDesc = db.TextProperty()
```

But of course, if one or the last four results are repeated, just shows me and what I want is to get the last not repeated four rows, and I do not know how I can do that...

Any suggestions? (I think, if at the end this is possible, could be with a totally different sentence, but I don't mind ;))

Any help much appreciated.. Sorry for my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GQL does not support DISTINCT queries. The closet you can do is put the results into a set and check how many entries are in a set. If less than four, query for additional records.

This answer is more in depth: [Python: DISTINCT on GQuery result set (GQL, GAE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239258/python-distinct-on-gquery-result-set-gql-gae)

Otherwise, such distinct list need to be pre-computed. GAE follows a mantra of expensive writes to enable super-fast reads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try something like put the results into a set (I need date ordered result). You have given me a good idea, thanks ;)

Comment: In order to save money, try this pattern:
`a) get last four results; use a set with the key you want to be unique
b) while results < 4
c) run a query for one entity on unique_property < lowest_value
d) if you run out of results early, just break and return`

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword was introduced in [release 1.7.4.](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/12/app-engine-174-released.html).

You can find the updated GQL reference (for example for Python) [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference).